# Angular router guard with Django

Tags: django, angular

I am using django authentication, I want to use angular router guards when not signed in. So that it reroutes to login page if not logged in.

I have tried to setup as angular usually would with router guards, but this routes to the url without a trailing slash which doesn't work with Django. I have fixed it so it keeps the trailing slash, but this doesn't route to the Django page, it seems its looking for a Angular page. But if it type in the url for the Django login page that still works.

Auth Guard:

```
checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    this.router.navigate(['/accounts/login/.']);
    return false;
}
```

app-routing module:

```
{
  path:"",
  component: ProjectHomeComponent,
  canActivate : [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: 'view', component: ProjectViewComponent },
        { path: 'seeManage', component: ProjectManageComponent },
        { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expect to be routed to django login page, not routed to django login page

Comment: Are you using Django rest framework?

Comment: yes but I'm currently using plain django for the user authentication

Comment: Try using Django rest for user authentication. Angular router doesn't play well with other routes

Comment: How can I stop a user from just typing in the url to a section I don't want them to access until they're logged in